# textbox array only dispalying 1st word of a string from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a SUBJECT table in MySQL database whose value i am retrieving in a php page with textbox array. while retrieving its only showing the 1st word of the string in the textbox.
For example -- Subject Name "Intro to C" but in textbox its showing only "Intro". Pls see the code for reference --

```
     <table width="400" border="1">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="4" valign="top"><div align="center" class="style4">Subject(s) Details</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
<td width="87"><strong><span class="style1">Select </span></strong></td>
<td width="87"><strong><span class="style1">Subject ID </span></strong></td>
<td width="270"><strong><span class="style1">Subject Name </span></strong></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
            $i=0;
            $result = mysql_query("select sub_id,sub_name from subject where crs_id='$cid' and sem_id='$smid' order by sub_id asc")
            or 
            die(mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
?>
  <tr>
<td><span class="style1"><?php echo "<input name=t1[] type=checkbox value=".$i." checked />"; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style1"><?php echo "<input name=t2[] size=15 type=text  value=".$row['sub_id']." />"; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="style1"><?php echo "<input name=t3[] size=30 type=text  value=".$row['sub_name']." />"; ?></span></td>
 </tr>
  <?php
        $i++;
        }
 ?>
   <tr>
<td colspan="4"><div align="center"><input name="submit" type="Submit" value="Update Subject(s)" />
</div></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code, you'll need to wrap your database values inside of single quotes `'`:

```
<?php echo "<input name=t3[] size=30 type=text  value='".$row['sub_name']."' />"; ?>
```

If not, the html is interpreted as:

```
<input name=t3[] size=30 type=text value=Intro to C />
```

By the way, this is best practice for all html attributes:

```
<?php echo "<input name='t3[]' size='30' type='text'  value='".$row['sub_name']."' />"; ?>
```

results in:

```
<input name='t3[]' size='30' type='text'  value='Intro to C' />
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply echo it using `{}` like below

```
echo "<input type=text  value='{$row['sub_name']}' />";
```